# Как правильно оформить select запрос последней записи столбца

Tags: mysql, sql

Как правильно оформить select-запрос в SQL, который берет только последнею запись со столбца `finished`?

Вот скриншот таблицы
[image: Скриншот таблицы]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно ка-то так:

```
SELECT `finished` FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `finished` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Этот запрос выдаст запись, в которой дата завершения наиболее поздняя.

Если же нужно получить запись, которая была создана последней, поменяйте поле в `ORDER BY` на `created`.

```
SELECT `finished` FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Последняя запись не обязательно будет содержать максимальное значение поля `finished`, в вопросе речь шла именно про последнюю запись

Comment: @cassius, какая запись в Вашем понимании считается последней? Если нужна последняя запись по дате создания, то просто поменяйте поле в `ORDER BY`.

Comment: в моем понимании, последняя - которую вставили последней, но я не автор вопроса и не знаю он имел ввиду.

Comment: @Streletz,благодарю вас за ответ !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `finished` FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Ваше решение нерабочее. Автоинкремент может пойти по кругу если будут удаления.

Comment: Зачем минусовать за неточность? Тем более данный ответ был дан первым. По-моему лучше предложить автору улучшить ответ. @Автор, замените id на finished в ORDER BY.